# In which nucleophilic aromatic substitution rate is faster m-fluoronitrobenzene or p-fluoronitrobenzene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

In which nucleophilic aromatic substitution rate is faster: *m*-fluoronitrobenzene or *p*-fluoronitrobenzene?

Comment: SNAr on m-nitrofluoro species is by several orders slower than p-nitro

Answer (score 3):

The rate of reaction *depends* on **stability of intermediate**. The given reaction follows $\ce{S_N2Ar}$ mechanism through "Meisenheimer intermediate". So, the stability of "Meisenheimer" primarily drives the reaction.

> ortho and para isomer are almost same except their **position**, which is the main reason why is the former reacts *much slowly* than the latter.

In the *ortho* isomer, the negative charge of the ring isn't delocalised with $\ce{NO2}$, whereas in the *para* isomer, it is delocalised, as seen in the following image,

[image: mechanism difference]

(Source: [Master Organic Chemistry](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2018/08/20/nucleophilic-aromatic-substitution-nas))